# Can I test Ubuntu Cloud in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, cloud

I was wondering if there was any way to install Ubuntu Cloud (Nodes and Clusters) inside VirtualBox just to see how things work, before I actually use multiple machines to do the job?

I know if it is possible the system will be very slow, but its just a one time trial to see how things work if I setup my own cloud.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you install Ubuntu Server and then the cloud tools. You should try the image described here: [Ubuntu Cloud Live](http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2011/10/ubuntu-cloud-live/). Probably it's a better start than installing a bunch of os's. You can use it to boot real machines or as a vm disk.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, will definitely check it out! Going to start experimenting with cloud now :)